# Play 2.3.x framework doesn't run JUnit tests in child project

Tags: java, build, playframework-2.0, sbt, junit4

I am using Play 2.3.4, IDEA 13.1.5 Ultimate and am trying to write some JUnit tests in code structured with `activator new experimentApp play-java`.

Besides the Root module (which is pretty much unchanged to the original template), there is a Child module to it with standard directory structure so:

- sources in `src/main/java` -> contains 1 class called `org.net.ClassOne`
- tests in   `src/main/test` -> contains 1 test class called `org.net.ClassOneTest`

Both of these classes are in Child module.

Code for the classes is trivial:

ClassOne:

> public class ClassOne {
>
> ```
> public String test() {
>     return "Smoke test";
> } }
> ```

ClassOneTest:

> public class ClassOneTest {
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void simpleCheck() {
>     int a = 1 + 1;
>     assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
> }
>
> @Test
> public void smokeTest() {
>     ClassOne smoke = new ClassOne();
>     assertThat(smoke.test()).isEqualTo("Smoke test");
> } }
> ```

My Root `build.sbt` config is this:

```
.....
lazy val Root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .aggregate(child)
  .dependsOn(child)

lazy val child = project in file("Child")
.....
```

Since the Root module is unchanged from the `play-intro-java` template, it contains its original classes directly under `test/` directory and on running `activator clean compile test` both of the classes get run regularly.

However, the JUnit test in the Child module (the class quoted above) in Child module are completely ignored on `activator clean compile test`. If I try to run `ClassOneTest` from IDEA, it runs without errors, which tells me classpath is formed correctly however I am missing some activator/sbt configuration part.

Just to make things totally obvious, running `activator clean compile test` on:

- Root module yields:

> [info] Done updating.
>
> [info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to
>   R:\intellij-projects\Root\target\scala-2.11\classes...
>
> [info] Compiling 2 Java sources to
>   R:\intellij-projects\Root\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
>
> [info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3 [success]  Total
>   time: 15 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 10:22:26 AM

- Child module yields:

> [info] Done updating.
>
> [info] Compiling 1 Java source to
>   R:\intellij-projects\Root\Child\target\scala-2.10\classes...
>
> [success] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 10:47:11 AM
>
> [info] Compiling 1 Java source to
>   R:\intellij-projects\Root\Child\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
>
> [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 10:47:12 AM

So the questions are:

- why is `activator` failing to notice JUnit tests in Child module only? It runs the tests in Root module fine and I would expect `activator` to pick all tests up when run in Root module, let alone Child module,
- why is `activator` disregarding the directive `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.1"` placed in Root `build.sbt`? It is only after I place this expression in Child `build.sbt`, the classes are compiled in expected directory, i.e. `...\scala-2.11\...`

I have read the other SO questions and:

- `clean` doesn't fix the issue
- `@RunWith(JUnit.class)` is not placed in my tests

---

EDIT: As I suspected, after amending the Root `build.sbt` with

```
lazy val Child = (project in file("Child")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

and placing the `ClassOneTest` directly under `test/` and `ClassOne` under `app/`, all the tests are correctly executed when running from Root, so

`activator clean compile test`

`...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to R:\intellij-projects\Root\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[success] Total time: 10 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 11:20:40 AM
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to R:\intellij-projects\Root\Child\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to R:\intellij-projects\Root\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 11:20:47 AM`

Interestingly, running the `activator clean compile test` from Child doesn't invoke any tests(?). Surely, there must be a way to tell Play where the test classes are at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to do what I want - which is to have separate project settings in Root project (default Play settings as this will be the web-app using Child jars) and Child project(s) (which will be just jars contributing logic to web-app).

The solution is to amend Root and Child `build.sbt`s in this way:

Root

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava)
  .aggregate(child)
  .dependsOn(child)

lazy val child = (project in file("Child")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

Child

```
// compile-scoped directories
javaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "src/main/java"

resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "src/main/resources"

scalaSource in Compile <<= baseDirectory / "src/main/scala"

// test-scoped directories
javaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory / "src/test/java"

resourceDirectory in Test <<= baseDirectory / "src/test/resources"

scalaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory / "src/test/scala"
```

produces

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to R:\intellij-projects\esi-load\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 2
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to R:\intellij-projects\esi-load\target\scala-2.11\test-classes...
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[success] Total time: 17 s, completed Oct 7, 2014 12:58:47 PM
```

There were several key insights here:

- `activator` seems to be oblivious to projects that don't have `enablePlugins(PlayJava)` called on project construction
- once that is realized, a chance discovery lead me to this [Play 2.0.4 page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/SBTSettings) listing all the default Play settings - for the reasons I can't understand, these settings have been deleted from [Play 2.3.4 page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/SBTSettings). It was then trivial to override those settings in Child `build.sbt`

Point 2) tell me that is either an oversight or there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach so if there is a better way to do this, I would be very interested to hear it. Until that time, I am (reluctantly) accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should understand a little more sbt, so I'd recommend reading through some of the introductory sbt docs (activator is just a UI for sbt).

Play is called a framework instead of a library because it is a fundamental approach to how you develop your app. One effect of that is that it changes the default source organization from `src/main/java|scala` to just `app`. <s>If you enable Play on your root project *and* you aggregate all sub-projects, this effect will be project-wide</s>. **Edit**: This is incorrect, your subproject does *not* use Play if you don't enable the plug-in on it explicitly.

<s>So if you want your subproject not to be a Play project, your root project shouldn't be a Play project either.</s>

Personally, when I'm using sub-projects, I'm not using the root project as something runnable, but only as a container for global configurations and settings. Using the root project as your main app is perfectly fine, though.

**Update**:

After some testing, this must have to do with JUnit and sbt (Play already handles this for you). I've setup a Scala project with one Play-subproject and one normal sub-project, and everything works fine. When I run `sbt test` on the root project, all tests are executed.

`dependsOn` is only required when one project depends on the code of another one.

Comment: I understand activator essentially wraps sbt and have read through the documentation, this is [relevant](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html). However, the documentation page doesn't mention plugins are inherited in case of aggregation. My understanding was aggregation was done only on dependency-management level (so the dependencies from root are inherited all the way down unless excluded). I also understand that Play represents an application developing paradigm and I accept that - is my approach (potentially) problematic?

Comment: Yes you are right, something isn't working as expected.

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour? What do you regard as wrong?

Comment: According to the [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/SBTSubProjects) your approach should work. Maybe they didn't check tests, though.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page here - in essence, the activator won't pickup the tests in the child module unless I enable PlayJava plugin on the child module as well AND the child module contains identical directory structure as root module. If this is the issue you're referring to, then yes, I agree - I was following their recommendations in documentation but I had to "hack around" in order to make it work. Do you think we should raise an issue on Play GitHub repo?

Comment: No worries, let me know what you think.

Comment: I have confirmed the behaviour - it is only after specifying `.aggregate(child)` that the Activator picks up the child project and starts running tests on it. What's even more surprising is `.dependsOn(child)` doesn't seem to influence the Activator at all. If this is by design, it needs to be stated clearly in the docs - though I would question such a design choice.

Comment: I tried this out, works perfectly for me. See updates to the answer.